# Postgres 9.6 transaction does not complete where expected with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I asked a vague question a few days ago, now I'd rather give a concrete example. Here is a sample database that I'm going to insert items to:

[image]

At the beginning of execution it's empty. Here is my C# code for inserting the example items:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var insertables = GenerateItems();
    var context = new TestDbContext();

    foreach (var item in insertables)
    {
        Insert(item, context);
    }
}

public static void Insert(Table1 t, TestDbContext context)
{
    SimpleLog lg = null;

    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //force an error on purpose
            if (t.Name == "Item3" || t.Name == "Item4" || t.Name == "Item7")
            {
                t.Id = 1;
            };

            context.Table1.Add(t);
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            //clean the context so the error above does not persist
            context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.Entity != null).ToList()
                .ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);

            lg = new SimpleLog
            {
                Log = t.Name,
            };
        }
    }

    //my miserable attempt to log the erroneous item name
    if (lg != null)
    {
        context = new TestDbContext();
        context.SimpleLog.Add(lg);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private static List<Table1> GenerateItems()
{
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    return numbers.Select(n => new Table1
    {
        Name = $"Item{n}",
    }).ToList();
}
```

I am purposely causing exceptions for Item3, Item 4 and Item7 - by using an existing item id.

In my real scenario I have hundreds of thousands of txt files that should be read from the file system and inserted into the database as a multitude of table rows in different tables. Since some of my txt files are erroneous (let's say about 0.01%) I want to handle these errors in a transaction.

My real code is "inherited" and I don't want to start it from scratch, but it contains tons of code and about 50 calls to `SaveChanges()`. If for example the tenth call fails, I want the first 9 to be reverted - thus the transaction.

Basically what happened in my "real" database is that everything seemed to work perfectly, until I noticed that sometimes a faulty item would cause an exception, but not have its name logged in the DB. I opened the postgres logs and saw that INSERTS for my SimpleLog table happen in the transaction for the following item. So if two in a row end up being faulty, the first one would not get its error logged in the DB.

The same thing happens in my test code. Here are the results from my DB at the end of execution:

[image]

[image]

As you can see - Item3 is missing from the log table despite causing an exception.

I'm wondering - is this expected behavior or a bug? And is there a way to make logging happen in my `catch` block where the `SaveChanges()` is, and not in the next transaction - so I get my expected experience?

**P.S. Using EF 1.1.0 and PGSql 9.6**

**P.S.2: Adding `transaction.Dispose()` next to the rollback does not help my cause either**

Comment: I understand that you inherited ton of code, but at least you can change this part to save `SimpleLog` using new context instance. Doing rollback, then clearing change tracking entries, then saving new entity - that just begs for disaster.

Comment: Just tried this with a new context object - the result is the same. Please note that the longest line of code above is doing exactly that - cleaning up the old context.

I also tried to use a variable outside the using statement that gets filled within the catch block - and moved the LOG inserts after the using statement. The result is still the same.

Comment: So to clarify, you create completely fresh context, then do `context.SimpleLog.Add()` followed by `SaveChanges` and that still becomes part of the next transaction somehow? As for that line - I don't think it really fully clears context (that is - is complete analog of creating new context).

Comment: Indeed. And Item3 does not get logged. Item9 doesn't either (for some reason). Edited code in the question for visibility.

Comment: Hey @nikovn this is already happening in new .NET Core and Postgre versions?

Comment: @Martin I'm having a hard time reproducing this now, and unfortunately I'm not working on this same codebase anymore, so I can't check.